# Sending Email Using SMTP4DEV in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I plan to do a powershell script for sending a email to end user via SMTP4DEV. Before i implement my script, i started to execute the `Send-MailMessage` command in powershell CMD for test out the flow first. But i am getting the following error message

```
 Send-MailMessage : The operation has timed out.
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

I tested telnet to my `SMTP4DEV`, there's no anything blocking. I believed it's not required any credential for authentication because when i want to check my email, i am not required to login and just key in the url for checking the email.The online doc for `SMTP4DEV` also didnt shown any authentication required. My `SMTP4DEV` is running in `HTTP`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $From = "sender@domain.com"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $To = "support@domain.com"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Subject = "test"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Body = "test"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SMTPServer = "x.x.x.x"
PS C:\Windows\system32> $SMTPPort = "2222"
PS C:\Windows\system32> Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port
 $SMTPPort
```

The sender and recipient are dummy user

Comment: are you using port 2222 for smtp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your SMTP really configured on port 2222?

The standard SMTP ports are 25 (default SMTP port), 465, & 587. Also smtp4dev has default port as 25 mentioned in their [README.md](https://github.com/rnwood/smtp4dev/blob/master/README.md)

refer to this blogs for more references [which smpt port should I use](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/which-smtp-port-understanding-ports-25-465-587/) and [smtp port to use](https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/what-smtp-port/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,my smtp running on 2222. But i found out where is the issue. i will share out the solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The powershell script is working fine for me

```
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
$to = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress($contractorEmail)
$from = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("accessmgmt@xxx.com")

$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to)
$msg.subject = "xxx Account Extension"
$msg.body = "Dear xxx <br>"  
$msg.body += "This is the email content and body <br>"
$msg.body += "Best Regards <br>"
$msg.body += "Team B" 
$smtp.host = "x.x.x.x"

$smtp.send($msg)
```

i am not sure what is the different between `send()` and `Send-MailMessage`